# Fill empty cells with VLOOKUP from other table

Tags: python, vlookup, isnullorempty

I have Agents table and Revenues table (see attached).  On Agents table, I want to fill the marginal revenue empty cells (only empty!) with the equivalent vlookup value in Revenues table (Join, Merge et cet just wont work). Many thanks !
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfMl8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJA2c.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have any minimal, reproducible example, but this should just work. Assuming your are using pandas and the column name is actually 'Agent ID'.

```
import pandas as pd
new_df = pd.merge(agents_table_df, 
                  revenues_df, 
                  on ='Agent ID', 
                  how ='inner')`
```